# CSS3: ¿Un transform-origin para cada transform?

Tags: css3

Supongamos que tengo dos transformaciones en la propiedad *transform*, Ej:

```
transform: scale(.5,.5) rotate(10deg);
```

Se que es posible establecer el punto de origen de las transformaciones utilizando la propiedad `transform-origin`, Ej:

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Pero ese punto de origen se aplicara para todas las transformaciones del objeto.

¿Hay alguna manera de indicar un punto de origen distinto para cada transformación?

Ejemplo usando el metodo que indica rnd

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
#a{
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display: block;
  transition:1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: left top 0;
}
#a:hover{
  transform:scale(.5);
}
#b {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition:1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  background-color:red;
  transform-origin: right top 0;
}
#b:hover {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
```

Comment: No puedes indicar más que un punto de origen. No creo que es necesario tampoco ¿Puedes mostrar una situación concreta en que quieres usar más que uno?

Comment: Era curiosidad, me extrañaba que no se pudiera, por ejemplo para rotar desde una esquina pero cambiar la escala desde otra, como el ejemplo editado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna manera de indicar un punto de origen distinto para cada transformación?

No puedes, pero siempre puedes usar dos elementos diferentes, y darle a cada uno un origen distinto.

```css
.externo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: scale(1, .5);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}

.interno {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="externo">
  <img class="interno" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 por ofrecer una alternativa para lograr un efecto similar al deseado

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación de W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-origin-property), sólo se puede especificar un único `transform-origin` que puede tener uno de los siguientes formatos:

> [ left | center | right | top | bottom | <percentage> | <length> ]
>
> o
>
> [ left | center | right |  | <length> ]   [ top | center | bottom | <percentage> |  ] <length>?
>
> o
>
> [[ center | left | right ] && [ center | top | bottom ]] <length>?

Es decir, el valor de `tranform-origin` puede tener 1, 2 ó 3 parámetros pero será un único valor (y no una lista de valores) que se aplicará al `transform` (que sí puede ser una lista).

Así que respondiendo a tu pregunta: no, no hay ninguna manera de indicar un punto de origen distinto para cada transformación porque sólo se permite un único valor, que se aplicará a todas las transformaciones indicadas en `transform`.